# Discord.py How to set commands for specific user's depending on user id

Tags: python, discord.py

I want my discord bot to put a cooldown whenever someone uses any command but only if the message author id is not in my list called results.
y = how many times you can use the command.
z = cooldown in seconds.
Somehow it does not work at all.
When I type in $lucky there is no response at all.
Thanks in advance

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')
y = 0
z = 0

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):    
    with open(r'path') as f:   
        content = f.readlines()
        content = [x.strip() for x in content]
        results = list(map(int, content))
        user_id = message.author.id
        if user_id in results:
            y = 99999
            z = 1
            return (y,z)
        else:
            y = 1
            z = 10
            return (y, z)
    await bot.process_commands(message)



@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(y, z, commands.BucketType.user)
async def lucky(message):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work at all because you're not retrieving the information from the `on_message` event, also you cannot get the values returned from an event. My suggestion - use the `global` keyword and edit the global variables

```py
y = 0
z = 0

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global y, z

    with open(r'path') as f:   
        content = f.readlines()

    content = [x.strip() for x in content]
    results = list(map(int, content))
    user_id = message.author.id

    if user_id in results:
        y = 99999
        z = 1

    else:
        y = 1
        z = 10
    
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Also I'm unsure if this is gonna work, when the cooldown is once set, it's not possible to dynamically change it.

EDIT:

Deleting the cooldown for certain users

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 10.0, commands.BucketType.user)
async def foo(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Foo")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Check if the user is in the file and shouldn't have a cooldown
    if "user is in file":
        context = await bot.get_context(message)
        # Check if the command is in cooldown, optional step
        if foo.get_cooldown_retry_after(context): # `foo` is the command
            # Reseting the cooldown
            foo.reset_cooldown(context)
        
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

#### Reference:

- [`Bot.get_context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_context)
- [`Command.get_cooldown_retry_after`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.get_cooldown_retry_after)
- [`Command.reset_cooldown`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.reset_cooldown)

Comment: Yes, I now get a: name 'y' not defined error in the @commands.cooldown line.

Comment: You also need to define them in the global scope, you're simply overwriting them in the event

Comment: You were right it does not work.
Bot doesn't do anything at all

Comment: Well the cooldown is not working, there is a way to bypass it tho

Comment: and how would that be?
EDIT: it successfully posts command now but it does set y = 9999 and z = 1 for everyone

Comment: You can check out the edit, also remember to accept the answer if it helped